Two times cart adding
i have an issue you have to solve it, generally in my webstite i put a click here to join button. that redirecting to course list. once the customer redirect to that they will press add to cart. then our website will tell to register. but the problem is that
after registration cart will be empty again they have to add.
but i have placed some tools from many webstite even before registration we are adding the cart it will be there. why in our tutor LMS asking two times.
i want it like this. after registration it should be proceed to check out.
now people doing add to acrt ...... registration.... again add to cart.... proceed to checkout...
i want it like
add to cart... registration........ proceed to chcekout...
any idea..
bro lots of people registing my website but no one is placing ordernmay they might confused in this extra step ... help ...help.... help
go to my web site and check you will get more idea there is one purple colur button.. click here to join
My website is a tutor LMS based website
i ask hostinger they forwarded your name

hi please read How do I ask a good question? and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?
